# How do you create a wrapper for filter in R that takes two arguments?

Tags: r

I have to create a filter that:
Takes two arguments: a dataframe (df) and a country name (country_name).

Checks to see if there is a column called “country” or “Country”. Note - a few functions check column names. We used names in class.

If there is a country column, filter the data by the country specified with country_name and return just the filtered data.

If there is not a country column, return “No country data”.

I tried:

```
# sample data
df=data.frame(country_name)
```

Hoping to be able to create a data frame but instead I got an error symbol. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Help us help you — please read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/17303805) on how to effectively ask an R question on stackoverflow. You can then [edit] your post to include example data, code you’ve tried so far, and any errors you’ve gotten.

Comment: Hello, [here](https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/02-func-R/index.html) is a straightfoward explanation on how to create functions in R, also an R introductory course in general with RStudio.